# Regex match a word that starts with a string

Tags: java, regex

How to generate a regex to match only one word which starts with `big`

I have tried to form a regex with start and end string. Starting string as `big` and ending string as `\s` space.

Consider this line `You are my big-big-big friend and also a brother`

When i use the below regex, it gives me result as `big-big-bigfriendandalsoabrother`

```
(.big.*\s)
```

But i am expecting result as `big-big-big`. The word can be at starting of line or at the end. I want to generate a regex to match the full word which starts with `big`

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use `(?<!\S)big\S*`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Its really great. Working without any issue. Can you please share knowledge how it works?

Comment: I have added an answer. Sorry for lack of demos and example code, I am on a mobile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following regex may be used:

```
(?<!\S)big\S*
```

Details:

- `(?<!\S)` - a negative lookbehind that makes sure there is start of string or a whitespace immediately to the left of the current location
- `big` - a literal substring
- `\S*` - any 0 or more chars other than whitespace chars

Comment: What's the difference in using `\b` to match the beginning word boundary and `(?<!\S)`?

Comment: Did some testing, - counts as a word boundary

Comment: `\b` before `big` will match only if the `big` is not preceded with a word char. It is equal to `(?<!\w)big`. `(?<!\S)big` will match only if there is no non-whitespace char (i.e. a whitespace boundary). Since your expected matches are not consecutive word chars, but all non-whitespace chars, a whitespace boundary makes more sense.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Regex

```
(?!\s)big\S*
```

It'll match exactly what you asked for.

Explanation:

```
(?!\s)
```

It may or may not have a whitespace behind it, but it shouldn't be counted as part of the capture (negative lookahead)

```
big
```

Will find the word **big**

```
\S*
```

Will find any character that's **NOT** a whitespace, 0 or more times

So:

```
(?!\s)big\S*
```

Finds the word **big**, followed by anything that's not a whitespace, until it hits a whitespace. It may or may not have a whitespace behind.

Comment: Thank you. But it fails when the word at the end.

Comment: `(\S+)` should find 1 or more times, not 0 or more times

Comment: Indeed. I fixed it, could you verify?

Comment: @phflack that's true, I edited it at the exact same time you were typing your comment :P

Comment: Thanks for your help. But @Wiktor answered already in comment. Regret that cannot accept your answer.

Comment: There's no problem, his answer is also correct :) I answered due to it not being in answer, but just in a comment, and the it's better to have an answer. I wouldn't delete my answer after he answered his, so we'll have 2 answers and that's fine